# flowplayer html validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flowplayer

Ok, Im trying to rebuild a clients website thats long over due for cleanup on the backend and under the hood. This client uses flowplayer for most of the videos seen on any of there sites, and while attempting to validate my code via w3c validator I notice that the validator is throwing 2 errors both pertaining to flowplayer in this case.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fv2.newyorkbarshow.com%2Fhome&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3

I am using the latest flowplayer out, and following there example (which I don't know if that validates either). So I am wondering if it doesn't validate out of the box, if anyone happens to know a means of correcting it so it will validate.

Comment: A quick peak shows that Flowplayer does not validate out of the box. In this case, it's not a terrible concern. It will gracefully degrade for those who don't support it, or for those with javascript off, it will still successfully show the HTML 5 video player.

Comment: With that I am happy, its one of the reasons why I choose flowplayer a while back, but now that the client site in question is being remodeled, I am attempting to make it validate to standards of W3C, I can't get full validation without correcting this issue, trival as it is in almost all aspects, but the client wants clean optimized code that validates cleanly. Which isn't easy with todays means of delivering content.

Comment: basically what the validator wants is either a `data=` or `type=` attribute added to the `object` to validate it. @Hardik has the proper value needing to be added to the `data` string in order to maintain site validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add data attribute with value "/static/imgs/static/VidAd4BarShow.swf" in your object tag.

note : I see this happens before flow player executes anything within your source...

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean? Do I add this to the link that flowplayer uses to create the flash player instance, or do I add this to the flowplayer object on the page somehow?

Comment: i see you have <object> tag generated before javascript executes. and i was telling to add my code in that object code. or if you could share your code on pastebin or someother site i can review and tell you exact problem.